# Multiple prices for multiple countries

Tags: e-commerce, web, hierarchy, pricing

I'm working on a multiple countries project. Until now, we only sold to one country, but we're working on letting users from its neighbour country (speaking the same language) buy our products.
For legal reasons, products don't have the same price, depending on where the user is living. And we don't know (for sure, because we can try to guess) where new user lives.

So, now I'm having trouble deciding a few things :

- on product pages, should the "historical" price should be bigger ? (Since most of the customer base lives in the "historical country")
- how should I label the prices with a flag? with the country name?

[image: Trying stuff for prices]

- on listing pages (where space is counted), I'm hesitant as displaying two prices (and maybe more in the future). But "From XXX" doesn't feel right neither as the price cannot be decided by the user (it depends from her address). What is less worse?

Thanks for the feedback :)

Comment: Just ask which country they're in first or have the browser geolocate them. Those are pretty reliable methods. Then you only have to show the price that applies to them.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**Showing multiple prices should not be an option.**

You can think a lot of reasons for that, like misunderstanding of users, perception of users, possible longer lists for countries which will be added in the future etc...

So, you should show just **one price**, which leads us to another question: **which price?**

You can find many answers for this another question based on technologies you are effectively using. Briefly: auto detecting of location e.g. using dns server user uses, asking permission to user to find its country or in worst case directly asking to user.

Comment: Thanks! I didn't mention it before, but we did planned to try to guess the country and eventually ask the user, but I was thinking it would be optionnal, and that's why I wanted a fallback. Now, I'm rethinking this, maybe in this case, the country should be mandatory because it's less worse than displaying multiple prices

Answer (score 1):

I would try to determine the user's location first and if you are unable to do that, simply ask them to select their country in a simple prompt and store it in the session so you can use it later with shipping and other configurations.

Comment: Actually, this was planned, but as an optionnal prompt, so I wanted a fall back. I may rethink the optionnal part then!

Answer (score 0):

I agree with this approach: at first you should try to predict what the user location is, then give users the option to make changes. 
Also, depending on your use case, it might be important to remember that the user location at the moment of purchase may be different than his country of purchase

[image]

Comment: Yes, for our products, its the country of residence which is important.